# unable to built android app in android studio

Tags: android, android-proguard

> Error:(16, 0) Could not find method runProguard() for arguments
>   [false] on BuildType_Decorated{name=release, debuggable=false,
>   testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false,
>   pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false,
>   renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true,
>   signingConfig=null, embedMicroApp=true, mBuildConfigFields={},
>   mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[],
>   mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType. Open
>   File

This is my excretion when I try to built android studio project then I am getting this Exception please tell me or suggest how to fix it. Even I changed          runProguard false  to minifyEnabled  false but still same issue I am getting

Comment: Please post your gradle file. Which gradle version you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `"minifyEnabled false/true"` istead of `"runProguard false/true"`, your build types config should be like below;

```
buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Decrease gradle version, Clean project or restart android studio debuggale =true